# Java Raspberry PI WS2801

Tags: java, led, raspberry-pi3

Today i saw a YouTube Video where someone connected the WS 2801 LED Strip to a Raspberry Pi. I need to say that it looked realy cool so, i thought about buying a Strip too and genereting some nice Light effects, but then i got the problem that i dont know how i could control a Specific LED (for example the 4th LED) to glow in color x (for Example Green) and the other LED's in another color like red.

So the question in short: how i can control a Specific LED from the Strip with java and which components i need for it.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you link video

Comment: Also this is very off topic for this site. You will want to look for the raspberry pi site

Comment: :x sry i'm new with this but here is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sEkKMPufvc